# Copy a image on a new larger image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I have a color image `sourceImage` and I would copy this image on a new larger color image `destImage`: the source image should be centered over the new image. In order to perform this procedure, I wrote the following code:

*destHeight*: the height of the new larger image
*destWidth*: the width of the new larger image

*sourceFilename*: the path of the source image

```
sourceImage = cv2.imread(sourceFilename,1)
imgHeight, imgWidth, imgChannels = sourceImage.shape[:3]
#print sourceImage.shape[:3]

destImage = np.zeros((destHeight,destWidth,imgChannels), np.uint8)
#print destImage.shape[:3]

yBorder = (destHeight-imgHeight)/2
xBorder = (destWidth-imgWidth)/2
#print yBorder, xBorder

destImage[yBorder:imgHeight,xBorder:imgWidth] = sourceImage
cv2.imshow('dst', destImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But when I run the script, the python interpreter displays the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples.py", line 30, in <module>
    destImage[yBorder:imgHeight,xBorder:imgWidth] = sourceImage
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

What is the reason for this error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
destImage[yBorder:yBorder + imgHeight,xBorder:xBorder + imgWidth] = sourceImage
```

The slice syntax is `start:stop`, not `start:width`.